# ProgressBar not tegerring with javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I was building a desktop app using javafx.
my fxml file is:-

```
<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ch.Buildsapp.Main.BuildsController" fx:id="ap">
<children>
  <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="14.0" spacing="20.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
     <children>
          <ComboBox fx:id="versionCombo" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="108.0" promptText="7.0 Win">
            <items>
          <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="Win" />
            <String fx:value="Mac" />
            </FXCollections>
        </items>
              <value>
          <String fx:value="Win" />
      </value>
          </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox fx:id="versionNo" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="89.0" promptText="7.0" />
          <Button fx:id="downloadButton" minWidth="80.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Download" />
          <Button fx:id="installButton" minWidth="80.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Install" />
        <ComboBox fx:id="locCombo" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="103.0">
        <items>
          <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="CJ" />
            <String fx:value="MN" />
            </FXCollections>
        </items>
        <value>
          <String fx:value="CJ" />
      </value>
        </ComboBox>
            <ProgressBar fx:id="progressBar1" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="102.0" progress="0.0" />
     </children>
     <padding>
        <Insets left="10.0" right="3.0" top="5.0" />
     </padding>
  </HBox>
    <TableView fx:id="tableView" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="2.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="2.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="40.0">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="builds" prefWidth="482.0" text="Builds" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="date" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="124.0" text="Date" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="release" prefWidth="168.0" text="Release" />
        </columns>
    </TableView>

 </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

my controller class for download button is :-

```
downloadButton.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        download();
    }

});
```

the download method is as follows.

```
private void download() {
    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPConnection().makeConnection(loc);

    try {
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        success = ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(PATH + preset + "/" + file_to_download + offset);
        System.out.println("Download Path:-" + PATH + preset + "/" + file_to_download + offset);
        if (!success) {
            System.out.println("Could not changed the directory to RIBS");
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Directory changed to RIBS");
        }
        FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles();
        for (FTPFile file : files) {
            if (file.getName().contains(".zip")) {
                dfile = file.getName();
            }

        }
        fileMap.put("build", dfile);
        primaryStage = (Stage) ap.getScene().getWindow();

        String homePath = System.getProperty("user.home");
        File downloadPath = new File(homePath + "\\LightroomBuildss\\" + osVer);
        if (!downloadPath.exists()) {
            if (downloadPath.mkdirs()) {
                System.out.println("Directory is created!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
            }
        }
        // System.out.println(chosenDir.getAbsolutePath());
        filePath = new File(downloadPath + "/" + dfile);
        if (filePath.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File altready exist");
            return;
        } else {
            fileMap.put("path", filePath.toString());
            fileMap.put("kind", "RIBS");
            Task task = new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void call() throws IOException {
                    try {
                        output = new FileOutputStream(downloadPath + "/" + dfile);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    ftpClient.sendNoOp();
                    ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(1000);

                    Task<Void> sleeper = new Task<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Void call() throws Exception {
                            try {
                                for (double progress = 0.0; progress < 100.0; progress++) {
                                    Thread.sleep(100);
                                    updateProgress(progress, 100);
                                    System.out.println(progress);
                                }
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            }
                            return null;
                        }
                    };
                    ProgressBar slider = startProgressBar();
                    slider.progressProperty().bind(sleeper.progressProperty());
                    Thread thread = new Thread(sleeper);
                    thread.start();
                    if (ftpClient.retrieveFile(dfile, output) == true) {
                        downloadButton.setDisable(true);

                        outsize = dfile.length();
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };
            Thread t = new Thread(task);
            t.start();

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (output != null) {
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my progress bar code is :-

```
    public ProgressBar startProgressBar() {
    Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
    ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(0);
    ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator(0);
    pi.progressProperty().bind(pb.progressProperty());
    HBox hb = new HBox();
    hb.setSpacing(5);
    hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    hb.getChildren().addAll(pb, pi);
    Scene scene = new Scene(hb, 300, 100);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    return pb;
    }
```

I am calling the startProgessBar method from in download method before the download begins but after the method is called the progress bar doesn't start and the code written after the method call(disabling download button in this case ) also doesn't get executed although the builds are downloaded at the required folder. If the startProgressBar method is not called the code after it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of things wrong.  First, don't put the window setup for the progress indicators inside the task.  Set it up, then define the task and run it.

I don't see any link between the task progress and the screen.

Modifying the slider based on it's valueProperty doesn't seem to make it update on the screen.  Better to link directly to the ProgressBar through a binding.

Here's some simple code that does what you're looking for, with a dummy operation in the task instead of the download:

```
public class SampleTask extends Application {

private BorderPane testPane;

class TestPane extends BorderPane {

    public TestPane() {
        Button button = new Button("Click Here");
        setCenter(button);
        button.setOnAction(evt -> {
            Task<Void> sleeper = new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {
                    try {
                        for (double progress = 0.0; progress < 100.0; progress++) {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                            updateProgress(progress, 100);
                            System.out.println(progress);
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };
            ProgressBar slider = startProgressBar();
            slider.progressProperty().bind(sleeper.progressProperty());
            Thread thread = new Thread(sleeper);
            thread.start();
        });
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Task Progress Tester");
    testPane = new TestPane();
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(testPane, 300, 250));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public ProgressBar startProgressBar() {
    Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
    ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(0);
    ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator(0);
    pi.progressProperty().bind(pb.progressProperty());
    HBox hb = new HBox();
    hb.setSpacing(5);
    hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    hb.getChildren().addAll(pb, pi);
    Scene scene = new Scene(hb, 300, 100);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    return pb;
}
```

}

Comment: I have updated my code as in question but I am still not able to start the progress bar.

Comment: Well, now you have a task inside a task, which I don't think is the way you want to go.  Also, it looks like you're defining the progress bar inside the outer task, which would give you a "Not FXAT" error if you actually tried to put it onto the screen, which you aren't doing. If you look at my example, you'll see that the screen setup is done outside of the task definition, in the event handler for the button - which is executed on the FXAT, then that code binds the progress property of the task to the progress bar.

Comment: The biggest problem that you'll have is that the FTP client (if you're using the Apache version) doesn't have any progress indicator on the file transfer.  So you'll have to find a multi-threaded way to monitor the file progress for yourself.  I'd suspect that would mean getting the file size through the ftp client first; then launching a second thread that monitors the destination file on the local file system for size and updating the task progress property accordingly.  Then start the file download, and kill the monitor thread when complete.  Do the second thread manually, not another task.

Answer (score 0):

Check these.

```
primaryStage=//this is global
primaryStage= (Stage) ap.getScene().getWindow();//why do this?
//i guess its simply primaryStage = primaryStage
```

also

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root);//scene already has a root
scene.setRoot(hb);//why do this?
//if you do not need the Group, why set it to your scene
```

also

```
(Stage) ap.getScene().getWindow();//this a.k.a primaryStage is already shown
primaryStage.show();//this isn't needed as your last line.
```

These above doesn't solve your problem though, but this does with the help of the above

```
startProggressBar();
if (ftpClient.retrieveFile(dfile, output) == true) {
       downloadButton.setDisable(true);//this guy is an orphan.
       outsize = dfile.length();
 }
//when startProggressBar(); is done your primaryStage's Scene is changed
```

Hope its helpful

Comment: @EIItz  I have defined Stage primaryStage as a global variable so didn't I need to set the primaryStage to my current stage??          and you explain the second and third point briefly I am new to javaFx it will be a great help.